# How to make lots of api calls without fail?

Tags: python, api

I have written a program to easily manage products on a webshop. Unfortunately the webshop's api is a bit wonky, this results in crashes.

The program needs to create and update stock on a daily bases, this takes thousands of api calls because nothing can be done in one step. For example, creating a product, adding a picture and a category takes three calls. Updating a product takes two calls.

---

**Current solution**

`time.sleep()` is used to control the amount of calls, there is a maximum of 100 calls per minute.

To retry calls a loop with a try block is used. After a few tries the call gets skipped.

The current solution is okay but not good enough, it sometimes crashes.
The error is given by [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (I use it to call the webshop api.)

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

---

I'm looking for a way to make the api calls without crashing and skipping as few calls as possible.

Comment: `time.sleep()` is not a good way of meeting this requirement since you can't tell how much time a call would take in a deterministic way. Better way would be using a timer and counting your calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gregburek/1441055) on how to implement a rate limiting decorator for your function calls.